# Solving a family of congruences with variable moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099305/are-there-arbitrarily-large-sets-s-of-natural-integers-such-that-the-differenc),

I came upon the following family of equivalences

$$\left\{\begin{align}
   12n+8  &\equiv 0 \bmod{(x+4)}, \\ 
   12n+9  &\equiv 0 \bmod{(x+3)}, \\
   12n+10 &\equiv 0 \bmod{(x+2)}, \\
   12n+12 &\equiv 0 \bmod{x}
\end{align} \right \}$$

where I am seeking non negative integer pairs $(x,n)$ that solve all of the equivalences.

I tried $x=1,2,3,\dots$ until I found the solutions 
$$(x,n) = (12, 138+140m)$$

I'm pretty sure that there are other values of $x$ that lead to other solutions.

What I'm hoping for is a way to solve families of congruences similar to the above example without iterating over all possible values of $x$.

A few suggestions or hints would be nice.

Comment: I assume, from your solution, that this is existential on both $n$ and $x$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr : Yes, both $x$ and $n$ are non negative integer variables.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : You got it backwards, it's x divides 12.

Comment: Actually, neither are true because if $x=7$ and $n=6$, then ...